# Returning a subset of results from an array by slicing

Tags: php

I'm fetching some data from an API. There are 100 results, and different ones are used on different parts of the page. For this particular section I only want to render a subset of 10 of these.

So far, I'm using a foreach to loop over the initial data and pull all values from the specified key, and populate an array. I then want to take a slice of the array, then iterate over that, selecting only the 1st 10 elements. These will be what is echo'd to the page.

```
else {
    foreach($responseResult as $subject) {
        $uses = array($subject['subject']);
    }
    $uses = array_slice($uses, 0, 10);
    foreach($uses as $use) {
        echo "<tr><th scope='row'></th><td><a href='#'>{$use}</a></td></tr>";
    }
}
```

This currently doesn't produce anything on the page. The error log reveals an array to string conversion, as well as an invalid foreach argument. I know what the issue is, I just can't see how to correct it. #CodeFatigue

Comment: Hey daz-wuk, can you post your example data?

Comment: Hi Sebastian, I don't have a data sample but it's JSON data that has gone through json_decode, with the second parameter set to true, returning an associative array. The Key/Value pairs are [Subject] and [Description]. For each subject, I want to create a table row containing the [Description] text.

Comment: You could post a sample of the JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are continually setting `$uses` to an array of a single item.  Create a blank array and add in the items as you go along...

```
$uses = array();
foreach($responseResult as $subject) {
    $uses[] = $subject['subject'];
}
```

You may be able to simplify this to extract the element using [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) instead (depending on PHP version)...

```
$uses = array_column($responseResult, "subject");
```